# How can I make my command be at the end of the trigger?

Tags: discord.py

I want my command "promote GM" to be at the end of the trigger. Ex: !promote {user} GM. However, I'm not sure how to do this. The command that I have so far worked, but not in that layout.

```
@bot.command(aliases=["promote GM", "promote General Manager"])
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner")
async def q(ctx, member:discord.Member):
  guild = bot.get_guild(766292887914151949)
  role_name = discord.utilis.get(guild.roles, name="General Manager")
  embed = discord.Embed()
  embed.add_field(name="<:Green:786300903065518090> Success", value=f"{member.mention} has been promoted to General Manager.")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await member.add_roles(role_name)
```

I'm not exactly sure how to change the placement.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that is to add a "gm" statement at the end of your function. Like that, you could define your function as:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["promote"]) # Don't add "gm" here
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner")
async def q(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, gm=None): # Default value for gm: None
    # Check if user precised "GM" or "General Manager" as last statement:
    if gm != 'GM' or "General Manager":
    
    
        guild = bot.get_guild(766292887914151949)
        role_name = discord.utilis.get(guild.roles, name="General Manager")

        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.add_field(name="<:Green:786300903065518090> Success", value=f'{member.mention} has been promoted to General Manager.")
    
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await member.add_roles(role_name)
    
    else: # if user did not enter "GM" or "General Manager" as last statement:
        await ctx.send('''Please enter "GM" or "General Manager" at the end of the command.
Use the command like: `!promote {member} GM''')
```

By doing this, your argument can take in spaces.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do that, as arguments always come after the prefix and command name.
(see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Comment: I maybe didn't understand the question right, but there *is* a way of doing this. I covered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65346581/how-can-i-make-my-command-be-at-the-end-of-the-trigger/65347152#65347152